# vue js code is not getting update old code is still there

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vuejs3

i am developing electron JS application using VueJS now my issue is even after i change the code in a file it's not getting updated now my new code is there but with this name offlineHandler.js?a123 and offlineHandler.js also there but with my old code and there is no my new code.

[image]

This is my old code which after changes not getting added to real offlineHandler.js

```
const dns = remote.require("dns");
const { parse } = remote.require("url");

let url = "https://www.google.com/";
class OfflineHandler {
  CheckNetworkStatus() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const { protocol } = parse(url);
      const lib =
        protocol === "https:"
          ? remote.require("https")
          : remote.require("http");
      const request = lib.get(url, (response) => {
        resolve(response);
      });
      request.on("error", (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  }
}
export default new OfflineHandler();
```

and this my new code which code with my new update

````
  CheckNetworkStatus() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (navigator.onLine) {
        resolve(true); // Device is online
      } else {
        reject(false); // Device is offline
      }
    });
  }
}

export default new OfflineHandler();```
````